# Unable to copy files to Nexus 7 / Android KitKat

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, file-transfer

I've got brand new, factory-based, un-tweaked ASUS Nexus 7 II (2013) LTE tablet and I'm completetly unable to copy more than just a few files between my PC and tablet.

Steps, that I repeat every time are painfully obvious:

- plugs these two devices together,
- wait until Nexus device appears in Windows,
- open source folder window (any on Windows disk),
- open destination folder (any on my Nexus device),
- select some files or folders in source and drag them to destination.

Copy process starts and stops after sending about 10-20 files. On Windows side, copy progress freezes forever. On Nexus side, you see beatuful message saying that `com.android.media` process is halted.

I can repeat these steps over and over again. Changing cables, using different computers, restarting source computer or Nexus itself, all for nothing -- my Nexus 7 breaks file transfer after receiving about 20 files (sometimes it breaks after getting just one).

I know, that MTP protocol is very, very unstable and forcing users to use it (i.e. removing native USB support in Android 4.x) is a Google very not funny joke. But, for God sake, how can I copy my 20k photo collection to my brand new Nexus tablet, if it breaks copy transfer every tenth files?

Is this an identified bug, or with Android 4.4.2 Google decided, that we won't be able to copy files to our own devices at all? And the only way to get them there, will be to use stupid Google Drive?

Is there any fix or work-around to this problem? Other than my own solution, as stupid as setting up local FTP server, installing FTP client to my Nexus and copying files that way, through FTP protocol?

Comment: Did you try a download manager type of app that would resume broken downloads?

Comment: This question is about copying files natively, through Windows. It does not offer any resume functionality. Using 3rd party software with resumed downloads in my idea of solving this problem. But, that is not, what this question was about.

Comment: Thats why its a comment.

Comment: The other answers pretty much tell you the same thing that i stated in my comment.

Answer (score 2):

I was in the same boat as you for a while. I guess you could use FTP but I was looking for something more.

I now use [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid) to transfer files over Wi-Fi. I have transferred files as big as 10GB and have no complaints. Plus it saves messing around with the cable and drivers.

Answer (score 0):

MTP issues, related to Drivers.  Also present on 2012 Nexus 7. I've learned that you're better off using a 3rd party software like Wondershare mobile GO or Moborobo etc to transfer files. Other stuff they can do is a bonus. Try it, you will like it.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use Solid Explorer Pro. Check out its "File Sharing" option and create a FTP server with password protection. Then create its widget on your home screen.

Now, in your PC > My Computer ... Right Click in an empty area > Add a network location ... Now add that FTP address you created in your tab.

This method is HIGHLY convenient for you but might give trouble on large file transfers (due to MTP) so better use it only with music or photo transfers.

Answer (score 0):

I use either FTP (FastFTP on the Nexus, Cyberduck on the Mac), or more often, Dropbox, which is always running on my desktop, and DropSync Pro on the Nexus. Then files just 'appear' on the Nexus, possibly after a manual sync if I want to use those files before the next DropSync autosync is due (I keep it infrequent for battery life).

Answer (score 0):

See https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2840804?hl=en#ts=3457048.  I tried the suggestion to change the storage setting to PTP which led to a new hardware installation of software on my (Windows) computer, and then rechecking MTP, which also led to software installation.  After that, I was able to use the USB connection for file transfer.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem, and it was being caused by the 360 Security app. Uninstalling that fixed the issue.